# Jquery nth-child not working as expected

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get child radio inputs. The results are very strange. Here's the html:

```
 <div id=transactionTabs>
    <input type="radio" id="transtab1" name="transactionTabs" value="tab1"></input>
    <label for="transtab1" class="noTransactions">Tab 1 <span>0</span> </label>

    <input type="radio" id="transtab2" name="transactionTabs" value="tab2"></input>
    <label for="transtab2" class="noTransactions">Tab 2 <span>0</span> </label>

    <input type="radio" id="transtab3" name="transactionTabs" value="tab3" checked="checked"></input>
    <label for="transtab3" class="selected">Tab 3 <span>1</span> </label>

    <input type="radio" id="transtab4" name="transactionTabs" value="tab4"></input>
    <label for="transtab4" class="noTransactions">Tab 4 <span>0</span> </label>
```

and the Jquery:

```
    var $element = $('#transactionTabs');

    console.log('1st child is ');
    console.log($element.find(':radio:nth-child(1)'));

    console.log('2nd child is ');
    console.log($element.find(':radio:nth-child(2)'));

    console.log('3rd child is ');
    console.log($element.find(':radio:nth-child(3)'));

    console.log('4th child is ');
    console.log($element.find(':radio:nth-child(4)'));

    console.log('5th child is ');
    console.log($element.find(':radio:nth-child(5)'));
```

Strangely, it's only working with odd numbers. The 2nd and 4th child are not found. I would expect the second child to be: "input#transtab2" but nothng is found...

Comment: because the odd children are input elements where as even one's are label..

Comment: Why not just `$element.find('[type=radio]').eq(0)` etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]:nth-child(1)')
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

Your JSFiddle is empty, however your problem appears to be that you're using `:nth-child`. The `:nth-child` selector pulls the *n* child element, regardless of its type (meaning `:radio:nth-child(2)` is null as `:nth-child(2)` is the `label` element).

Instead you want to use [the `:nth-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type):

```
$element.find(':radio:nth-of-type(1)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:eq()` along with `.filter()` in this context,

```
var $element = $('#transactionTabs :radio');

console.log('1st child is ');
console.log($element.filter(':eq(1)'));

console.log('2nd child is ');
console.log($element.filter(':eq(2)'));

.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  **[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**  selector to get the element

```
 var element = $('#transactionTabs input[type=radio]'); 
 element.eq(0);
```